# Run bash from .Net Core independent from main process linux c#

Tags: c#, linux, bash, .net-core

Hi have a service which needs to execute it's updated shell script independent from the .Core process. I have tried /bin/bash, /bin/nohup and /bin/setsid. But every time the script stops the systemd service the script seems also to be stopped. How do I get this independent?

```
private static Process StartLinuxUpdateScript(string pathToUpdateScript, string pathToUpdateZip)
    {
        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "/bin/setsid",
                UseShellExecute = true,
                Arguments = $" bash {pathToUpdateScript} {pathToUpdateZip}"
            }
        };
        return process;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it helpfull:

```
 public void RunProcess(string fileName, string arg)
        {
            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    FileName = fileName,
                    Arguments = arg ,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                },
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };

            process.Start();
            string processOutput; 
            while ((processOutput = process.StandardError.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(processOutput);
            }

            process.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: thanks...but i don't want to wait for the process. The started process will stop my systemd service, which means I can't redirect output or do a read line. I just solved the update process by overwriting files and restarting the systemd service, since I can overwrite the files during the service is running. but still wonder if it is possible to execute a shell script independent of the main process

Comment: you can create new thread and run shell on it. i want you can see any error on your program. if you want shell run to other thread use fire and forget extention  function